# How to create mutiple directories with sub-directories?

Tags: c#, io, subdirectory, create-directory

I have this stuation. I would like to create 12 subdirectories from the root, 30 subdirectories from each subdirectory at index 1 and 24 subdirectories from each subdirectory at index 2. I know that:

```
DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(@"c:\Users\Public\Root");
```

creates one subdirectory everytime. How to do that in one shot? (just for example the first 30).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell what you actually want, however this might point you in the right direction.

Declare your directories:

```
var rootDir = @"C:\SomeRoot";

var directoryList = new List<string>()
{
   "dir1",
   "dir2",
   "dir3"
};
var subDirectoryList = new List<string>()
{
   "subDir1",
   "subDir2",
   "subDir3"
};
```

Method

```
private void CreateDirectories(string root, List<String> directoryList, List<String> subDirectoryList)
{
   foreach (var dir in directoryList)
   {
      var currentDir = Path.Combine(root, dir);

      foreach (var subDir in subDirectoryList)
      {
         Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(currentDir, subDir));
      }

   }
}
```

Usage

```
CreateDirectories(rootDir,directoryList,subDirectoryList)
```

Output

```
C:\SomeRoot\dir1\subDir1
C:\SomeRoot\dir1\subDir2
C:\SomeRoot\dir1\subDir3
C:\SomeRoot\dir2\subDir1
C:\SomeRoot\dir2\subDir2
C:\SomeRoot\dir2\subDir3
```

Comment: I am guettig this error message: Argument 2 and 3: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>. this is under usage. I use string instead for var. Any idea why?

Comment: i did update a while ago, it had a couple of errors, try now, ive tested it does compile and work

Comment: same problem.                                                    var directoryList = new List<string>()
{
   "dir1",
   "dir2",
   "dir3"
}; --> i get: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' to 'string'. I had to write Convert.ToString(), but it didn't work.

Comment: try List<string> directoryList = new List<string>() { "dir1", "dir2", "dir3" };

Comment: Also which line is it breaking on, the directoryList line?

Comment: both of them (the directoryList and the subDirectoryList). I will frame the code and hang it on the wall.

Answer (score 2):

There is no method to create multiple *independent* directories at once. However, note that the `Directory.Create()` method will create all of the directories named in the target path. E.g. if the `C:\Users\Public\Root` directory is empty, then calling `Directory.Create(@"C:\Users\Public\Root\one\two\three");` will create the `one`, `two`, and `three` subdirectories required, all in that single call.

You can take advantage of that to create just the lowest-level directories you need, which would at least avoid the initial 12 subdirectory operations. You would still need to create the individual 30, 24, etc. subdirectories in individual calls.

(Your question is pretty vague about what you're actually trying to do so I can't say exactly what would happen beyond that, without more details).